# Wordpress: How can I keep market checkboxes in searchform after submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I created a custom post type with custom taxonomies and a function for get terms of taxonomies in checklist. In searchform I call this function in accordion. My problem is when I like keep market checkboxes in searchform. The theme is a child theme Avada.How can I do it?

My functions.php

```html
/*===================================================
Show taxonomies in checklist
=====================================================*/
function get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args){
 $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
 $output ="<fieldset name='".$taxonomies."'><ul>";
 foreach($myterms as $term){
  $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
  $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
  $term_slug=$term->slug;
  $term_name =$term->name;
  $link = $term_slug;
  $key=$taxonomies;
  $output .="<li><input name='".$key."' type='checkbox' value='".$link."' />".$term_name."</li>";
 }     
 return $output;
```

My searchform.php

```css
/*General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
.accordion section:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
.accordion section:target:hover { background:#FFF; }
.accordion section:target h3 {width:90%;}
.accordion section:target h3 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
.accordion section:target p {display:block;}
.accordion section h3 a{padding:18px 20px;display:block; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none; }

/*set style of closed slide*/
.accordion section{ float:left;overflow:hidden; color:#333; cursor:pointer; background: #333; margin:3px; }
.accordion section:hover {background:#444;}
.accordion section p { display:none; }
.accordion section:after{position:relative;font-size:14px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{content:'1';}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{content:'2';}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{content:'3';}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{content:'4';}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{content:'5';}
.accordion section:nth-child(6):after{content:'6';}
.accordion section:nth-child(7):after{content:'7';}
/*End General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
.vertical section{ width:100%; height:40px;
 -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
   -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
 -ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
   transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*Set height of the slide*/
.vertical :target{ height:600px; width:97%; }

.vertical section h3 { position:relative; left:0; top:-5px; }

/*Set position of the number on the slide*/
.vertical section:after{ top:-60px;left:810px;}
.vertical section:target:after{ left:-9999px;}
```

```html
<div>
<form class="search" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" method="get"> 
 <div class="search-table">   
 <div class="search-field">                             
 <?php $search_text = __(" " ); ?>           
<div class="search_field"> 
 <input type="text" class="field"  value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>" onblur="if (this.value == '')  {this.value = '<?php echo $search_text; ?>';}" onfocus="if (this.value =='<?php echo get_search_query() ?>')  {this.value = '<?php echo get_search_query() ?>';} {this.name = 's';}" />  
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical">
    <?php
    $taxonomies = 'ciutats';
    $args =array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
    $ciutat_select=get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args); 
    ?>
 <section id="ciutat">
  <h3><a href="#ciutat"> <strong>Escull la ciutat</strong></a></h3>
   <p ><?php echo $ciutat_select; ?></p>
 </section> 
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical">
     <?php
    $taxonomies = 'districtes';
    $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
    $districte_select = get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args); ?>
 <section id="districtes"> 
 <h3><a href="#districtes"><strong>Escull el districte</strong></a></h3>
  <p><?php echo $districte_select; ?></p> 
 </section> 
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical"> 
  <?php
  $taxonomies = 'barris';
  $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
  $barri_select = get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args); ?>
  <section id="barris">
 <h3><a href="#barris"> <strong>Escull el barri</strong></a></h3>
 <p><?php echo $barri_select; ?></p> 
  </section> 
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical"> 
   <?php
   $taxonomies = 'ambits';
      $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
   $ambit_select = get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args); ?>
 <section id="ambits">
  <h3><a href="#ambits"> <strong>Escull l'àmbit </strong></a></h3>
  <p><?php echo $ambit_select;?></p>
 </section> 
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical"> 
   <?php
   $taxonomies = 'colectius';
   $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
   $colectiu_select = get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args); ?>  <section id="colectius">
  <h3> <a href="#colectius"><strong>Escull el col.lectiu </strong></a></h3>
  <p><?php echo $colectiu_select; ?></p>
</section>     
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical">  
  <?php
  $taxonomies = 'serveis';
  $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
  $servei_select = get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args); ?>
 <section id="serveis">
 <h3><a href="#serveis"> <strong>Escull el servei </strong></a></h3>
  <p><?php echo $servei_select; ?></p>
 </section>    
</div>
<div class="accordion vertical">  
 <?php
 $taxonomies = 'especificitatserveis';
 $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
    $especificitatservei_select = get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args);
    ?>
<section id="especificitatservei">
 <h3><a href="#especificitatservei">  <strong>Escull l'especificitat del servei </strong></a></h3>
<p><?php echo $especificitatservei_select; ?></p>
</section>   
</div>
          
</div>
 
  <div class="search-button">
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="&#xf002;" />
  </div> 
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks in advance all people for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Since your form method is `get`, all of these selections should be available to php in the `$_GET` superglobal or via javascript (read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) ).

Note that you shouldn't trust anything in `$_GET` directly. Always sanitize the data using either a [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data#Sanitizing:_Cleaning_User_Input) or [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

My functions php:

```html
/*===================================================
Show taxonomies en checklist
=====================================================*/
function get_terms_checklist($taxonomies, $args){
$myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
$output ="<fieldset name='".$taxonomies."'><ul>";
foreach($myterms as $term){
$root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
$term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
$term_slug=$term->slug;
$term_name =$term->name;
if ((isset($_GET[$taxonomies])) && ($term_slug==$_GET[$taxonomies]))
 {$output .="<li><input name='".$taxonomies."' type='checkbox' value='".$term_slug."' checked/> ".$term_name."</li>"; }
else {$output .="<li><input name='".$taxonomies."' type='checkbox' value='".$term_slug."' /> ".$term_name."</li>";}
}   
return $output;
}
```